# The location tab is missing from the products menu in WordPress woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, menu

I have a wordpress woo-commerce website I am using ASTRA theme. I have noticed that the "Location" tab missing from the "Product" menu. Even in the "Add New Product" page there is no field for adding location. Previously these option were visible but recently its missing.

I have checked if plugins are conflicting or theme is not compatiable but all is working properly. there are no conflicting themes and even ASTRA theme is well compatible with woo-commerce. Please help me resolve this issue.